# HTML/Javascript click counter not working

Tags: javascript, html, logic, counter

I'm doing up a "cookie clicker" style thing in HTML for my friend.

I've gotten the click counter to *kind of* work.
basically,  when you click the image, the number at the bottom should increase by one at each click. There are then buttons on the side that change the amount that the number increases by each click.
I.e: When you click the image without pressing the buttons, the number increments by one, when you press the "2 clicks" button, the number **should** increment by 2 each click.

When i click the buttons, they make the number increment by the given amount (on the button) and then clicking on the image does nothing...

There is also some logic that does not work.

Here is the code:
`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Inital click value
   var clicks = 0;
   
   //Click counters
   
   function clicklee1() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee2() {
    clicks += 2;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee3() {
    clicks += 5;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee4() {
    clicks += 10;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee5() {
    clicks += 100;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee6() {
    clicks += 1000;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   function clicklee7() {
    clicks += 1000000;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   };
   
   //Changing the "onclick" value of lee
   
   function changeclicks1() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee1();
   }
   function changeclicks2() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee2();
   }
   function changeclicks3() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee3();
   }
   function changeclicks4() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee4();
   }
   function changeclicks5() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee5();
   }
   function changeclicks6() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee6();
   }
   function changeclicks7() {
    document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee7();
   }
   
   //Unlockable logic
   
   if(clicks < 5) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 5) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = false;
   }
   
   if(clicks < 20) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton3').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 20) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton3').disabled = false;
   }
   
   if(clicks < 50) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton4').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 50) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton4').disabled = false;
   }
   
   if(clicks < 75) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton5').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 75) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton5').disabled = false;
   }
   
   if(clicks < 200) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton6').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 200) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton6').disabled = false;
   }
   
   if(clicks < 500) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton7').disabled = true;
   }
   if(clicks >= 500) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton7').disabled = false;
   }
  </script>
<img id="lee" src="lee.png" height="300" width="300" onclick="clicklee1()">
  <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
  <div class="unlocks" style="text-align: right;">
   <button id="changebutton1" onclick="changeclicks1()">1 Click</button><br>
   <p>Requires 5 clicks</p>
   <button id="changebutton2" onclick="changeclicks2()">2 Clicks</button><br>
   <p>Requires 20 clicks</p>
   <button id="changebutton3" onclick="changeclicks3()">5 Clicks</button><br>
   <p>requires 50 clicks</p>
   <button id="changebutton4" onclick="changeclicks4()">10 Clicks</button><br>
   <p>Requires 75 clicks</p>
   <button id="changebutton5" onclick="changeclicks5()">100 Clicks</button><br>
   <p>Requires 200 clicks</p>
   <button id="changebutton6" onclick="changeclicks6()">1,000 Clicks</button><br>
   <p>Requires 500 clicks<p/>
   <button id="changebutton7" onclick="changeclicks6()">1,000,000 Clicks</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your post.

First is that script is before html, which prevent 
`document.getElementById` to work, because html is not yet completely parsed. It should be after, or wrapped in a a window.onload or equivalent function.

Second is pointed by another answer, `onclick` takes a function as argument, not the result of its evaluation.

Third: having one special function for each click step is very spagetthi code like. Why not having a step which could change when you click on your buttons?

Finally, your last if statements are executed only once, when they should be each time `click` value change

You can either wrap that in a function which you invoke each time you click on the image, or use observables such as in [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). To keep it closer to your input code I took the first approach.

```js
//Inital click value
var clicks = 0;
var step = 1;

//Click counters

function clicklee() {
  clicks += step;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  enableClicks();
};
//Changing the "onclick" value of lee

function changeclicks1() {
  step = 1;
}

function changeclicks2() {
  step = 2;
}

function changeclicks3() {
  step = 5;
}

function changeclicks4() {
  step = 10;
}

function changeclicks5() {
  step = 20;
}

function changeclicks6() {
  step = 100;
}

function changeclicks7() {
  step = 1000;
}

//Unlockable logic

function enableClicks() {
  if (clicks < 5) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 5) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = false;
  }

  if (clicks < 20) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton3').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 20) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton3').disabled = false;
  }

  if (clicks < 50) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton4').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 50) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton4').disabled = false;
  }

  if (clicks < 75) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton5').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 75) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton5').disabled = false;
  }

  if (clicks < 200) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton6').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 200) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton6').disabled = false;
  }

  if (clicks < 500) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton7').disabled = true;
  }
  if (clicks >= 500) {
    document.getElementById('changebutton7').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
#lee {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="lee" height="50" width="50" onclick="clicklee()">click me</div>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a>
</p>
<div class="unlocks">
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton1" onclick="changeclicks1()">1 Click</button>
    <p>Requires 5 clicks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton2" onclick="changeclicks2()">2 Clicks</button>
    <p>Requires 20 clicks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton3" onclick="changeclicks3()">5 Clicks</button>
    <p>requires 50 clicks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton4" onclick="changeclicks4()">10 Clicks</button>
    <p>Requires 75 clicks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton5" onclick="changeclicks5()">20 Clicks</button>
    <p>Requires 200 clicks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton6" onclick="changeclicks6()">100 Clicks</button>
    <p>Requires 500 clicks
      <p/>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="changebutton7" onclick="changeclicks7()">1000 Clicks</button>
    <p>Requires 2000 clicks<p/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` takes a function reference, not the value returned by the `function`.

Change this line (and similarly for others)

```
document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee1();
```

to

```
document.getElementById("lee").onclick = clicklee1;
```

> There is also some logic that does not work.

That logic needs to be inside a `document.onload` event handler since `document.getElementById('changebutton2')` will return null otherwise as this element has not been loaded into the DOM yet.

make it

```
document.onload = function(){
    if(clicks < 5) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = true;
    }
    if(clicks >= 5) {
            document.getElementById('changebutton2').disabled = false;
    }
    //rest of the logic
};
```